# Requirement for XNA with Surface

Tags: xna

I use the surface SDK for building cool multi-touch applications on Windows 7. I've the choice between WPF and XNA. I've already build a application based on XNA. Now I want to start this application on a other machine. Are there any requirement like frameworks which must be installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install the XNA Framework 4.0 (or whatever version you're coding against) Redistributable package on the other machine:
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=A88C6DEC-AEAE-42CD-A108-D35C013C3B97&displaylang=en

That should do it

Comment: It does not work. I've installed it. The error still appears.